# how to Import quickbooks desktop data to Online mysql server using php

Tags: php, mysql, quickbooks

Is it possible to import Quickbooks Desktop data directly to a live online mysql database using PHP ? For ex. if I connect using webconnect Quickbooks desktop to a local host server then this is connect string:-

```
    $dsn = 'mysql://root:@localhost/quickbooks'
```

So my question is instead of using localhost can I use Live server's credentials in order to import data ?

Or else do I first need to import desktop version's data into Quickbooks online version in order to achieve this ? Please help. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: In what format the data is exported?

Comment: Can't exactly figure out what you need with format... Its simply just import of Quickbooks data into a mysql Database . It is .sql format though

Comment: Try using phpmyadmin to import sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to import Quickbooks Desktop data directly to a live online mysql database using PHP ?

Directly? No. QuickBooks isn't based on an SQL database of any sort -- it's a proprietary data format, and you can only communicate with it via XML.

The closest you can get is either:

- Something like QODBC, which lets you query QuickBooks via a SQL-to-XML translation engine.

OR

- Something that does XML queries against QuickBooks to try to mirror data from QuickBooks into an SQL database (e.g. something like https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php which is what you're example $dsn string indicates you're using).

> So my question is instead of using localhost can I use Live server's credentials in order to import data ?

Um, what? Your questions kind of don't make a whole lot of sense, but...

You can use any database you want. It doesn't have to live on `localhost`. Just change the `$dsn` to where ever your database lives.

> Or else do I first need to import desktop version's data into Quickbooks online version in order to achieve this ?

QuickBooks Online is a completely separate product, that has absolutely nothing at all to do with QuickBooks for Windows. It's a completely separate product, with a separate API, a separate back-end data structure, developed by a separate team of developers, on a separate platform, in a separate programming language, etc.  The two share absolutely nothing in common outside of being developed by the same company. And neither will give you direct SQL access to the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a 3rd party solution. So your PHP generates Excel/CSV files which are uploaded into QB Online.

https://guruimporter.com/